# Pass a Hashtable as argument through a function to use for another function

Tags: powershell

I have a hashtable that I want to use for/like splatting

```
$hash = @{
         DeadlineDateTime = "31.12.2030 00:00:00";
         TimeBaseOn = "LocalTime"
}
```

This is passed through to a function

```
Test-Function -param1 "param1" -ht $hash
```

My Param section looks kinda like this

```
    [string]$param1,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [hashtable]$ht,
```

in the test-function I want to call another Function where the content of the hash is used as parameter. But it is not working

```
new-Function -param1 "param" @ht <-- Not working
new-Function -param1 "param" $ht <-- Not working
new-Function @ht -param1 "param"  <-- Not working
new-Function $ht -param1 "param"  <-- Not working
```

Any hint would be much appreciated

```
    Test-Function{
    param(
            [string]$param1,
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [hashtable]$ht,
    )
    
    new-Function -param1 "param" @ht
    }
    
####################
        $hash = @{
                 DeadlineDateTime = "31.12.2030 00:00:00";
                 TimeBaseOn = "LocalTime"
        }

    Test-Function -param1 "param1" -ht $hash
```

Comment: You need a space or a colon between the parameter name and argument value: `New-Function @ht -param1 "param"` (although it sounds like you want to pass `$param1` too, so: `New-Function @ht -param1:$param1`)

Comment: oh yes in the example.. But this is not the problem in my Script.
if  i use $ht i see the hashtabel if i use @ht it seems to be empty

Comment: Maybe I'm confused by the relation between these scripts - which one calls the other? And which one has the `param` section you've partially shown?

Comment: i create the hashtable 
Call Test-Function with the hashtable as Parameter and in the TestFunciton i start the New-Function with the Splatted Argument (Hashtable)

and the Param section is in the Test-Function

Comment: And what makes you think it's ultimately passing an empty hashtable to `new-Function`? Does `New-Function` attempt to inspect or print out the hashtable?

Comment: well the Paramters are not "used" i create a Collection in SCCM and those two Parameters are not set for the Collections. Just like it is empty. And when i pause it and hover over it it just shows "@ht = " and thats it

i updated my Question maybe it is not as conufsing as it was.

Comment: It honestly sounds like a problem with `New-Function` - your implementation of `Test-Function` is correct (assuming `New-Function` indeed has `$DeadlineDateTime` and `$TimeBaseOn` parameters defined)

Comment: New-Function is: New-CMApplicationDeployment and it has those Parameters. AND it creates the Deployment without issue. just those Paramters are not set... if i put it in fixed and not with Vars it works fine.. but i need it Variable because the Values are not always the same.

Comment: i think you are right the problem is something else.. when i do a write-host it shows the Parameters... i have to find another Way